# React Hook Form and DatePicker MUI validation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

How can i start validation when i click and select a date? Currently what it does:

- Validate on Submit click, so when field is empty, this is ok
- Validate on Submit click, when i selected date, this is ok
- Validate on date select but not clicking Submit, this does not work, but this is what I'm looking for.

```
import { Box, Button, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { DesktopDatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
import { AdapterLuxon } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterLuxon";
import { useState } from "react";
import type { FieldError, UseFormRegisterReturn } from "react-hook-form";
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export type TypeReactHookForm = {
  register: UseFormRegisterReturn;
  error: FieldError | undefined;
};

export const DatePicker = (p: {
  id: string;
  reactHookForm?: TypeReactHookForm;
}) => {
  const [open, openSet] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState<number | null>(null);

  return (
    <>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterLuxon}>
        <DesktopDatePicker
          inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
          onChange={setValue}
          onClose={() => openSet(false)}
          onOpen={() => openSet(true)}
          open={open}
          value={value}
          renderInput={(params) => {
            return (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                {...p.reactHookForm?.register}
                id={p.id}
                name={p.id}
                error={!!p.reactHookForm?.error}
                onClick={() => openSet(true)}
                type="date"
                inputProps={{
                  ...params.inputProps,
                  placeholder: "dd/mm/yyyy"
                }}
              />
            );
          }}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>

      {!!p.reactHookForm?.error && (
        <Typography sx={{ color: "red" }}>
          {p.reactHookForm?.error?.message}
        </Typography>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

type Inputs = {
  date: string;
};

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm<Inputs>();

  console.log(" ~ errors", errors);

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = (data) => {
    console.log(" ~ data", data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Box sx={{ width: "200px" }}>
        <DatePicker
          id="date"
          reactHookForm={{
            register: register("date", { required: "Required" }),
            error: errors.date
          }}
        />
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </Box>
    </form>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-resonance-w0pn8m?file=/src/App.tsx:0-2362